# Synchronization is not working - new thread coming inside syncronization block instead of having lock on it

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Multithreading, I am trying to Synchronize multiple request coming to method addRequestToPool,
New instance is created every time of class TicketRequestManagement and method addRequestToPool is called which will create thread and call further.

But it looks like when there are multiple request to addRequestToPool method which will further call synchronizeRequests the thread is not synchronized 2 thread will enter the code block instead of below synchronization code.

```
synchronized (this) {
        while (hashMap.containsKey(docketNo)) {
            wait();
        }
        hashMap.put(docketNo,1);
    }
```

Below is the complete code

TicketRequestManagement :

```
public class TicketRequestManagement {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TicketRequestManagement.class);

public SimpleActionResponse addRequestToPool(int docketNo) throws InterruptedException {
    logger.info("addRequestToPool started with Docket No : " + docketNo);

    SimpleActionResponse response = new SimpleActionResponse();

    RequestSynchronization requestSynchronization = new RequestSynchronization(docketNo);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                requestSynchronization.synchronizeRequests();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t1.join();

    return response;
}

public SimpleActionResponse removeRequestFromPool(int docketNo) throws InterruptedException {
    logger.info("removeRequestFromPool started with Docket No : " + docketNo);

    SimpleActionResponse response = new SimpleActionResponse();

    RequestSynchronization requestSynchronization = new RequestSynchronization(docketNo);

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                requestSynchronization.removeRequests();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    t2.start();
    t2.join();

    return response;
}

}
```

RequestSynchronization :

```
public class RequestSynchronization {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestSynchronization.class);
private static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private int docketNo;

public RequestSynchronization(int docketNo) {
    super();
    this.docketNo = docketNo;
}

public void synchronizeRequests() throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (this) {
        while (hashMap.containsKey(docketNo)) {
            wait();
        }
        hashMap.put(docketNo,1);
    }

}

public void removeRequests() throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (this) {
        hashMap.remove(docketNo);
        notify();
    }

}

}
```

Can you please suggest what is the thing I am doing wrong here and I would also like to know the scope of variable docketNo for each request coming will it remain sync with it's thread even after it goes to wait or there is some effect on it.

Thank you in advance !!

Edit 1 :

I have changed my access level to class level Locking and sending class instance instead of docket Number, below is my Modified method code but it looks like notify is not working now don't know why :(

```
    private final static Object lock = new Object();


public synchronized static void synchronizeRequests(RequestSynchronization requestSynchronization) throws InterruptedException {

        while (hashMap.containsKey(requestSynchronization.getDocketNo())) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        hashMap.put(requestSynchronization.getDocketNo(), requestSynchronization.getDocketNo());
}

public synchronized static void removeRequests(RequestSynchronization requestSynchronization) throws InterruptedException {

        hashMap.remove(requestSynchronization.getDocketNo());
        lock.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: You synchronize on different objects.

Comment: Expanding on what Johannes said, `synchronized(foo){...}` does _not_ stop two different threads from entering the block unless `foo` refers to the same instance in both threads.

Comment: FWIW, It never makes any sense to call `t2.start()` and then call `t2.join()` without doing anything else in between. The entire point of starting a thread is that it will do whatever it does _concurrently_ with whatever the parent thread does in between the `start()` call and the `join()` call. The parent thread in your code does _nothing_ in between `t2.start()` and `t2.join()`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to build, but do you know about the [`ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(k,v)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) method? You probably should take a look if you don't already know about it.

Comment: Hello @SolomonSlow I have used join to stop excution of existing thread until it is completed from synchronizeRequests() of class RequestSynchronization.

Comment: I am able to achieve Locking via class level lock but it seems my notify is not working or not invoking the sleeping thread.

Comment: Unfortunately I have nor used ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(k,v) , I will read about it.

Comment: `t2.start()` followed by `t2.join()` is entirely equivalent to `t2.run()` except for all the overhead involved in creating the thread and then waiting for it to finish. It's pointless.

Comment: Okay @user207421 Got it !!

Comment: When I am running my code with 2 concurrent request only Request 1 completes synchronizeRequests , Request 2 is not getting to wait state, don't know why :(

Comment: Re, "I have used join to stop excution of existing thread." That is not what `join()` does. When you call `t2.join()`, it doesn't do anything at all to the `t2` thread. All it does is _wait_ until the `t2` thread has finished its work.

Comment: Hello solomon, Yes I am trying to do exactly the same the Thread t2 should wait until it finished it work, I assume if we perform wait on this thread it wil hold the execution till notify is called. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.